# @Input model, how can I update the model fields without mapping one by one?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, primeng

In an Angular Component (A PopUp) where you can configure tables and their respective Zones
[image]

These Zones are editable, and whenever you click on a edit icon in a zone row, a component is initialized under the respective row to edit the zone (allowing multiple edits to occur on the same page)
[image]

Right now, I manage to edit the zones, cancel the edits, but I don't like my approach and am looking for suggestions.

Let me share the code first:

**dialogue-ref-externe-table.component.html**

```
          <p-table [paginator]="true" [rows]="40" [rowsPerPageOptions]="[20, 40, 60]"
                   [value]="refExterneZonesModified" [totalRecords]="refExterneZonesModified.length" styleClass="p-datatable-striped p-datatable-sm">
            <ng-template pTemplate="header">
              <tr>
                <th scope="col">Nom</th>
                <th scope="col">Type de la zone</th>
                <th scope="col">Position</th>
                <th scope="col">Longueur</th>
                <th scope="col">Sévérite Contrôle</th>
                <th scope="col">Obligatoire</th>
                <th scope="col">Cle</th>
                <th scope="col"></th>
                <th scope="col"></th>
              </tr>
            </ng-template>
            <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-zone>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  {{ zone.nom }}
                </td>
                <td>
                  {{ zone.type }}
                </td>
                <td>
                  {{ zone.position }}
                </td>
                <td>
                  {{ zone.longueur }}
                </td>
                <td>
                  {{ zone.severiteControle }}
                </td>
                <td>
                  <span *ngIf="zone.obligatoire">
                   <i class="pi pi-check" style="color: green"></i>
                  </span>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <span *ngIf="zone.cle">
                   <i class="pi pi-check" style="color: green"></i>
                  </span>
                </td>
                <td class ="action-column">
                  <button pButton type="button" icon="pi pi-pencil" class="p-button-rounded p-button-text action-button"
                          title="Modifier" style="color: black" (click)="editZone(zone)"></button>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <p-confirmDialog [style]="{ width: '50vw' }"></p-confirmDialog>
                  <button pButton type="button" icon="pi pi-trash" class="p-button-rounded p-button-text action-button"
                          title="Supprimer" style="color: black" (click)="deleteZone(zone.id)"></button>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr *ngIf="zone.saisieZone">
                <td colspan="9">
                  <app-saisie-zone [zoneModel]="zone"/>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </ng-template>
          </p-table>
        </p-fieldset>
```

**ref-externe-zone-model.ts**

```
      id?: number;
      refExterneTableId?: number;
      nom?: string;
      description?: string;
      type?: string;
      position?: number;
      longueur?: number;
      cle?: boolean;
      obligatoire?: boolean;
      severiteControle?: string;
      controles?: RefExterneControleModel[];
      saisieZone: boolean = false;

}
```

**saisie-zone.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-saisie-zone',
  templateUrl: './saisie-zone.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./saisie-zone.component.scss']
})
export class SaisieZoneComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() zoneModel: RefExterneZoneModel = new RefExterneZoneModel();
  @Output() close: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
  @Output() added: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
  @Output() modified: EventEmitter<RefExterneZoneModel> = new EventEmitter<RefExterneZoneModel>();

  severitesControles: EnumRecord[] = [];
  typeDonnees: EnumRecord[] = [];
  valeurContraintes: EnumRecord[] = [];
  zoneModelModified = new RefExterneZoneModel();


  constructor(private enumService: EnumService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.zoneModelModified = {...this.zoneModel};
    this.chargerEnums();
  }

  chargerEnums() {
      this.enumService.getEnum("SEVERITE_CONTROLE")?.subscribe(v => this.severitesControles = v);
      this.enumService.getEnum("TYPE_DONNEE")?.subscribe(v => this.typeDonnees = v);
      this.enumService.getEnum("VALEUR_CONTRAINTES")?.subscribe(v => this.valeurContraintes = v);
  }

  onConfirm() {
    this.zoneModel.id = this.zoneModelModified.id;
    this.zoneModel.refExterneTableId = this.zoneModelModified.refExterneTableId;
    this.zoneModel.nom = this.zoneModelModified.nom;
    this.zoneModel.description = this.zoneModelModified.description;
    this.zoneModel.type = this.zoneModelModified.type;
    this.zoneModel.position = this.zoneModelModified.position;
    this.zoneModel.longueur = this.zoneModelModified.longueur;
    this.zoneModel.severiteControle = this.zoneModelModified.severiteControle;
    this.zoneModel.obligatoire = this.zoneModelModified.obligatoire;
    this.zoneModel.cle = this.zoneModelModified.cle;
    //TODO Controles
    this.zoneModel.saisieZone = false;
  }

  onClose() {
    this.zoneModel.saisieZone = false;
  }
```

**saisie-zone.component.html**

```
<p-accordion [activeIndex]="0">
  <p-accordionTab header="Saisie de la zone: {{zoneModelModified.nom}}" >
      <p-fieldset legend="Attributes principaux">
        <div style="width: 50%; float: left">
            <label>Nom <label [style]="{ color: 'red' }">*</label></label>
            <input type="text" pInputText  [(ngModel)]="zoneModelModified.nom" class="p-field-element small-input-text" [style]="{ 'margin-left': '80px' }"/>
          <p></p>
            <label>Description</label>
            <textarea type="text" pInputText  [(ngModel)]="zoneModelModified.description" class="p-field-element" [style]="{ 'margin-left': '40px' }"></textarea>
          <p></p>
            <label>Position <label [style]="{ color: 'red' }">*</label></label>
            <input type="text" pInputText [(ngModel)]="zoneModelModified.position" class="p-field-element small-input-text" [style]="{ 'margin-left': '55px' }"/>
          <p></p>
            <label>Longueur <label [style]="{ color: 'red' }">*</label></label>
            <input type="text" pInputText [(ngModel)]="zoneModelModified.longueur" class="p-field-element small-input-text" [style]="{ 'margin-left': '45px' }"/>
        </div>
        <div style="width:50%; float: right">
          <p-checkbox [binary]="true" [(ngModel)]="zoneModelModified.cle"></p-checkbox>
          <label [style]="{ 'margin-left': '10px'}">Cle</label>
          <p></p>
          <p-checkbox [binary]="true" [(ngModel)]="zoneModelModified.obligatoire"></p-checkbox>
          <label [style]="{ 'margin-left': '10px'}">Obligatoire</label>
        </div>
      </p-fieldset>
      <p></p>
      <p-fieldset legend="Contrôles de la zone">
        <label>Sévérité des contrôles génériques <label [style]="{ color: 'red' }">*</label></label>
        <p-dropdown appendTo="body" [(ngModel)]="zoneModelModified.severiteControle" [options]="severitesControles" optionLabel="libelle"
                    optionValue="code" [style]="{ 'margin-left': '20px' }"/>
        <p></p>
        <label>Contrôle du type de donnée <label [style]="{ color: 'red' }">*</label></label>
        <p-dropdown appendTo="body" [(ngModel)]="zoneModelModified.type" [options]="typeDonnees" optionLabel="libelle"
                    optionValue="code" [style]="{ 'margin-left': '20px' }"/>
        <p></p>
        <label>Contrôle de valeurs</label>
        <p-dropdown appendTo="body" [options]="valeurContraintes" optionLabel="libelle"
                    [style]="{ 'margin-left': '20px' }" [showClear]="true" />
        <p></p>
        <button pButton type="submit" class="form-button" style="background-color: #0a7f5c; float: right; margin-left: 10px" title="ajouter"
                icon="pi pi-plus-circle" label="Confirmer" (click)="onConfirm()"></button>
        <button pButton class="form-button" style="background-color: rgb(128,128,128); float: right" title="annuler" icon="pi pi-times"
                label="Annuler" (click)="onClose()"></button>
      </p-fieldset>
  </p-accordionTab>
</p-accordion>
```

I don't like the fact that I have to map all the modified fields in the zoneModelModified to zoneModel. I do that because if I do this.zoneModel = this.zoneModified, it won't work, why? Because if I assign it like this and after that I do this.zoneModel.saisieZone = false, the saisie zone component won't close. Based on this code, do you have any suggestion on how to improve this?

Thanks

Comment: To update tbe model you can clean things up by writing `Object.assign(this.zoneModel, zoneModelModified)` or `this.zoneModel = {...this.zoneModel, ...this.zomeModelModified}`

Comment: That's it! I didn't know about the existence of this. Thank you!